# How to load a .txt file into textbox in html

Tags: html

I am making a kind of docs app, so far I have a text box and you can save what you type into the textbox as a .txt file. Is there a way to load the contents of the .txt file into that textbox?

```
'''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p style="text-align:left; font-size:50px; color:black;">CocoBread Docs</p>
    </body>
    <head>
    <title>Doc</title>
    <style>
        body
         {
            margin: 0%;
        }
    
        @font-face {
            font-family: "CG";
            src: url(./resources/CENTURYGOTHIC.ttf) format("truetype");
        }

        button {
            background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
            font-family: CG;
            border-color: rgb(119, 119, 119);
            border-width: 1px;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            padding-right: 20px;
            padding-left: 20px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            text-transform: capitalize;
        }
    
    
        textarea {
            margin-left: 0%;
            margin-top: 0%;
            height: 80%;
            width: 70%;
            resize: none;
            padding-bottom: 500px;
            padding-left: 0px;
            visibility: visible;
            background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
            border-color: rgb(119, 119, 119);
    
        }



    </style></head>
    
    
    <body>
        <textarea id="textbox" placeholder="Take Notes here and when you are ready to leave the app click the save to txt button"></textarea>
        <button id="create">SAVE TO FILE</button>
        <a download="Doc.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display: none"><button onclick="functionreset()">DOWNLOAD</button></a>
        <br>
        <script>
            (function() {
                var textFile = null,
                    makeTextFile = function(text) {
                        var data = new Blob([text], {
                            type: 'text/plain'
                        });
    
                        if (textFile !== null) {
                            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
                        }
    
                        textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
    
                        return textFile;
                    };
    
    
                var create = document.getElementById('create'),
                    textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
    
                create.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
                    link.href = makeTextFile(textbox.value);
                    link.style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('create').style.display = 'none';
                }, false);
            })();
    
            function functionreset() {
                var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
                link.style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('create').style.display = 'block';
            }
    
        </script>
        <script>
             document.getElementById("textbox").onchange = function() {functionreset()}
        </script>
    
    <!-- <iframe height=120% width=100%; src=./test.html></iframe>-->
    </head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coming Soon' rel='stylesheet'>
<style>
body {
    font-family: 'Coming Soon';font-size: 22px;
}
</style>
    </body>
    <script>
        document.body.style.background = "#dcdcdd"
    </script>
    </html>
'''
```

I am quite new to scripting as a whole so I would really appreciate the help. Now I will add a couple more random words and letters because I can't post because I have more code than text. bflerfguylergfliyergfiuerfgrefiycgerifgeriyfgerighferiyfyegferfigerfigeifgerfgerigfeiurgfierudfgierfreirefuerhfiuerfiuegrfigeriufgerifgreifgreigferigfieurgfilerugflieurfiuegfuergfueriugerigferfiherfurhdufhyrehfigefigiwfgiugwefgifugiwugfeiwefiuweifgieugfwieugfiwugfweisugfiewufiuhewgfewugfiugwefuigfiughweiufh.

Thanks,
Matthys

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JavaScript to do something like this

```
let input = document.querySelector('input')
  
let textarea = document.querySelector('textarea')
  
input.addEventListener('change', () => {
    let files = input.files;
  
    if (files.length == 0) return;
  
    const file = files[0];
  
    let reader = new FileReader();
  
    reader.onload = (e) => {
        const file = e.target.result;
        const lines = file.split(/\r\n|\n/);
        textarea.value = lines.join('\n');
    };
  
    reader.onerror = (e) => alert(e.target.error.name);
  
    reader.readAsText(file);
});
```